# I am looking for an alternative to Specifications for the given scenario

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I am calling `findall()` method of the JpaRepository as following

Service

```
on.findall(specificationsbuilder.getspecifications(params), paegable obj)  

specificationsbuilder.getspecifications(param)
```

returns specifications

My question is if specifications is null will my will findall(specifications,paegable) work

Comment: I suggest you try it to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [sourcecode of SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L400) it should work, because @Nullable says it will accept null:

```
@Override
    public Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable) {

        TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, pageable);
        return isUnpaged(pageable) ? new PageImpl<T>(query.getResultList())
                : readPage(query, getDomainClass(), pageable, spec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

read here : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-121, as of latest spring data jpa, the query will automatically form is null if your parameter is null.

Also, Since Spring data jpa 2.0, spring now supports @Nullable annotation. This can be helpful to handle null parameters passed.

*@Nullable – to be used on a parameter or return value that can be null.*

if the value is null it will automatically return true and if is not null, it will search that value in the table.